# run several .py file with local packages

Tags: python, projects

I have several projects in Python cloned from GitHub.

Every project needs to first run a `setup.py` file to install local packages next I run `main.py` file to execute the code.

How can I run all projects in one code (`.py` file)?

I would like to run the first project every minute and the second every 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need  a single `.py` file, a [cron](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/sysrescron-24589.html) job is what you want.

To setup a `cron` task, run this command:

```
crontab -e
```

It will open a text editor for you to create a new job. Write the following lines inside the text editor, for each line put your absolute path to the `main.py` file where indicated, then save. It should run your first project every minute and the second project every 15 seconds.

```
* * * * * python [path to *first* main.py]
* * * * * python [path to *second* main.py]
* * * * * sleep 15 && python [path to *second* main.py]
* * * * * sleep 30 && python [path to *second* main.py]
* * * * * sleep 45 && python [path to *second* main.py]
```

You can check that your job was saved correctly with the command `crontab -l` that lists your `cron` tasks.

I invite you to read some documentation on `cron` so that you can understand the format used by `crontab`. [Here is a good link](https://docs.acquia.com/article/cron-time-string-format)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but I need it implement it with python file

Comment: Even if you have a single `.py` that runs both of your project, you'll need something like `cron` to run you script every minute / every 15 sec. Why do you want a single file?